# Is there an option to read table from exe like msi?

Tags: c#, windows-installer, installation, exe, advanced-installer

I know that there is an option to read the msi tables, edit them and etc.
is there an option to do this to an exe file? 
I am building an installer which is an exe file.

an example to how the msi code will look like:

```
using (var database = new Database(@"D:\example-SetupFiles\example.exe", DatabaseOpenMode.Direct))
{
     database.Export("File", @"C:\Temp\data.txt");
     foo();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by installer with *.exe* extension ? are you referring to *setup.exe* file created along with *.msi* file ?

Comment: No, I have only setup.exe.

Comment: What did you use to create the setup.exe?

Comment: Added Advanced Installer tag for you.

Comment: Christopher is right, the EXE build by Advanced Installer is actually a bootstrapper for the MSI inside. You can extract it as documented. But, you can use it just to read its contents, not to modify and save it back in the EXE. For that you can try "EXE with files outside" build option, if you are not signing it digitally (in which case the bootstrapper will refuse to run the modified MSI - security check).

Answer (score 1):

It appears your installer is really an MSI inside of a self extracting EXE.  Please see:

[Advanced Installer User Guide](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/exe-setup-file.html)

```
Mypackage.exe /extract:"C:\My work"
```

Once extracted you can use other tools to reflect the MSI.